# How to set font color in SSRS matrix based on values range?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a matrix of numbers and I want to change a font color if a value is grater then 75% of all value's range.

```
=Switch(Fields!Total.Value>(Sum(Fields!Total.Value))*175/100, "LightGreen", Fields!Total.Value<Avg(Sum(Fields!Total.Value))*25/100, "Red")
```

...obviously does not work, because I make a sum on each cells and I don't know how to aggregate values outside a SQL Server.
Thanks.

Comment: The expression you include with this doesn't really help tell us understand what you are intending. Can you add some detail to the question to clarify what your in need of? I could guess, but I would more than likely be wrong.

Comment: I'm out of work now, so I can't append a picture, but lets say I have the matrix with days as columns and months in rows, so it shows number of transactions from each day in a year. Now, I want to set a color of number to red if that particular number falls in 90% of upper range of all values.

Comment: I think you may want to do this in the SQL of the data set. How you do that depends on the version of SQL Server. Look into `rank`, `percent_rank`, or one of the percentile functions built into SQL Server. Of course, I am assuming you are using SQL Server as your data store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `Fields!Total.Value` will be the same as `Sum(Fields!Total.Value)` in the detail rows of your table. You can specify one aggregate scope override like this:

```
=Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "<Your DataSet or Group Name>")
```

If you need anything more intricate than this, I would suggest using a subquery to get the aggregates at the scope you need. There are many other answers out there on how to do this.